# How to compile a library with a variable specified via command line?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I want to be able to provide a variable via a command line at **compile time**

```
MY_VAR="my_var1" cargo build

# or
MY_VAR="my_var111" cargo build

# or
MY_VAR="my_varfdsafdsafds" cargo build
```

and a library should be **compiled** with the value of a variable and see that value in its code. A library must not resolve a variable at runtime, but at compile time.

I don't consider changing the code of a library in any way, nor `.cargo/config`, nor `Cargo.toml`

How can I do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`env!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.env.html) macro to get the value of an environment variable at compile time:

```
let my_var: &'static str = env!("MY_VAR");
```

This will embed the value `MY_VAR` had during compilation into the binary, so it's available as a `&'static str` at runtime.